# Ajax Returns whole page content when user is not logged in - Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm using ajax to update clicks on post (post_meta). But the problem is, when user is not logged in wordpress, ajax returns whole page content. instead of what I want it to return.

Here's my code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Yt1jqzWe

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...and where is your function `mapsinputtitleSubmit2` ?? Also check out this example on how to use AJAX properly http://stv.whtly.com/2011/09/12/using-front-end-ajax-requests-in-your-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: Here is my js code http://pastebin.com/B2hVyFtG

Comment: Is it wrong to have two same ajax actions and one php function?

Comment: The AJAX actions are not the same, one is for privileged users (i.e. logged-in) and the other is for not logged-in ones (although they use the same PHP function, that means that you do not want to make difference between logged-in and not logged-in users).

Comment: yes, that's what I want. But, when user is not logged in it returns the whole page. Instead of `$current_likes`

Comment: Found a clue. When I'm logged in: on chrome network tab in developers mode, shows that a request is made to admin-ajax.php. And it's status is 200 (When I'm logged in)

But, when I'm not logged in, it's status is 302. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Problem !!!!

Another function hooked in `admin_init` was redirecting non logged in users. I just wrapped that in condition:

```
if(!defined('DOING_AJAX') and !DOING_AJAX){
    // redirection.
}
```